# How do I override a FILES rule?

Tags: htaccess

There is a directive that denies access to all index.html (file name used for example only).

```
<files index.html>
errordocument 403 http://mydomains.com/no-access.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>
```

How do I override the above directive to allow access to a *particular* instance of that file? The trick here is the the directory name comes from a WordPress database and is not an actual directory, just a path.

Some like the below is incorrect.

```
<files mobile/index.html>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Satisfy any
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't include the directory in a [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) directive; as mentioned in the documentation:

> The directives given within this section will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename.

If this is in the main server configuration or a vhost, you can embed it in a [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) directive:

```
<Directory "mobile">
    <Files "index.html">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Satisfy any
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

If it's in an `.htaccess` file, you can move the `<Files>` directive to `mobile/.htaccess` and it will only apply to that directory

Comment: Logs an error" "htaccess: <Directory not allowed here"

Comment: @mmcglynn Oh, for an htaccess file just put the `<Files>` directive in `mobile/.htaccess` and it'll apply to that directory

Comment: I edited the question.